# An expression evaluates to TRUE when it couldn't possibly be TRUE, could it?

Tags: javascript, logic, expression, evaluation, operator-precedence

I have the following check to see if an element should be considered "hovered over" or not.

I'm very confused because I'm seeing elements set to `state === 'hover'` when they should not be.

The `alert` message is even more confusing because it tells that the expression that just evaluated to true is one that shouldn't (if you think about it logically).

```
if( (ig.gui.cursor.pos.x >= element.pos.x) 
    && (ig.gui.cursor.pos.x <= element.pos.x + element.size.x)
    && (ig.gui.cursor.pos.y >= element.pos.y) 
    && (ig.gui.cursor.pos.y <= element.pos.y + element.size.y) 
    && !element.disabled ) {

    state = 'hover';

    alert(

        'This statement evaluates to true: '

        + ig.gui.cursor.pos.x
        + '>='
        + element.pos.x
        + '&&'
        + ig.gui.cursor.pos.x
        + '<='
        + element.pos.x
        + '+'
        + element.size.x
        + '&&'

        + ig.gui.cursor.pos.y
        + '>='
        + element.pos.y
        + '&&'
        + ig.gui.cursor.pos.y
        + '<='
        + element.pos.y
        + '+'
        + element.size.y
        + '&&'

        + ( !element.disabled )

    );

}
```

The above code results in `alert` messages like this:

[image: alert message]

Surely we can all agree that `580 <= 60 + 48` evaluates to `FALSE`, right?

And yet the alert was still called...

Comment: Use `console.log()` to confirm you're wrong (not `alert()`)

Comment: Are you sure they are all integers? Because I can see how the string "5.." <= "6..."

Comment: Is it possible that any of the values in your comparisons are strings?

Comment: To be sure, instead of doing `+ element.pos.x + '+' + element.size.x` do `+ (element.pos.x + element.size.x)` and see what you get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`element.pos.x` is a string ("60"). You'll need to convert it (and all the other strings in the comparisons) back into a number.

Comment: If you replace those `+`s with `-`s or use the prefix `+` operator then you'll be good to go.  `element.pos.x + element.size.x` -> `element.pos.x - -element.size.x` or `+element.pos.x + +element.size.x` since the subtraction operator and the prefix `+` operator both coerce their arguments to numbers.

Comment: If this answer is the case, and I believe it is, then you end up with `580>=60` and `580<=6048`, etc.